# Replacing characters at a certain index from string, using recursion

Tags: java, string, recursion, substring

Hi im trying to create a method to remove the spaces from a word recursively. Ive done this so far, and im really not sure why its not working.

```
public static String compact (String line)
{

    for (int x = 0 ; x < line.length () ; x++)
    {
        if (line.charAt (x) == ' ')
        {
            String newLine = line.substring (0, x) + line.substring (x);
            return compact (newLine);
        }
        else
            break;
    }
    return line;
}
```

This just returns the original string without removing any spaces.
Can someone please tell me what im doing wrong, thanks.

Comment: Why are you doing this? :/

Comment: Tip: remove the for loop, add a parameter to determine the currently selected character of your "char-array", doing this you can do a completely recursive loop, also don't forget that the count of characters changes since you're removing whitespaces, you have to give him the new string too.

Comment: But actually this is bad practice and I don't think that using recursion for something like this makes sense. If you want to practice recursion, do something with folders, deleting and so on.

Answer (score 4):

Just remove the

```
else break;
```

part, because if the first character of your String is not a whitespace, the loop will terminate

Also replace

```
String newLine = line.substring (0, x) + line.substring (x);
```

with

```
String newLine = line.substring (0, x) + line.substring (x + 1);
```

because you are actually not removing the whitespace, but copying the whole string over and over again. This is why you get a `StackOverflowError`.

---

The method should look like this:

```
public static String compact(String line) {
    for (int x = 0; x < line.length(); x++) {
        if (line.charAt(x) == ' ') {
            String newLine = line.substring (0, x) + line.substring (x+1);
            return compact(newLine);
        }
    }
    return line;
}
```

Comment: And replace `String newLine = line.substring (0, x) + line.substring (x);` with `String newLine = line.substring (0, x) + line.substring (x+1);`

Comment: @Noob, check out the updated answer. I've tested it and it works fine

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of the for loop and fix that in one line of code...

Just use..

```
  //changes a string "moon shine" to "moonshine"
  String newLine = line.trim().replaceAll(" +", "");
  System.out.println(newLine);
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure OP is doing this as a class exercise in recursion as opposed to thinking this is the best way to do this...